# ConstraintValidator always has null value during test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

after fixing a bug in an older Java Spring MVC 4.1 application, I wanted to add a unit test, but the method the current code base is using for testing won't actually execute validation.

So I wanted to add MVCMock, but when it executes the validation methods, the values passed to `isValid` is always null.

Relevant files below (I've tried to strip out as much noise as possible):

```java
// Unit Test
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class ExampleControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTestBase {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void fileUploadZipArchive() throws Exception {
        // Upload a zip file
        File mockFile = new File("src/test/resources/fixtures/ex.zip");

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder multipart = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .fileUpload("/files/ex/upload/Tex")
                .file("ex.zip",  FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(mockFile));

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(multipart)
                .andReturn();
    }
```

```java
// Bean
public class FileUploadBean {

    @Valid
    @MultipartMimeTypeMatch
    private MultipartFile file = null;

    // ...

}
```

```java
// Validator
public class MultipartMimeTypeMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MultipartMimeTypeMatch, Object> {

    // ...

    public boolean isValid(Object value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // value and context is always null
    }
}
```

```java
// Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{ex1}/upload/{ex2}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String ex1,
            @PathVariable String ex2, @Valid FileUploadBean fileUploadBean, BindingResult result) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
         // ...
     }
}
```

What could be going wrong?

NOTE: Spring 4.1

Comment: Where you have `ex.zip` it should be `file` as that is the name in your model object. The name should match the request parameter. Also what you posted doesn't make sense, are you writing a unit test with Mockito or are you using MockMVC? Those 2 methods don't match (nor make sense to use together).

Comment: I might remove my commentary with Mockito, that was the *existing* solution which also doesn't work

Comment: As mentioned `ex.zip` should be `file` in your test.

Comment: Well, that was the problem, thanks! Do you want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#file-java.lang.String-byte:A-) of the `file` method states that the `name` should be the name of the file. I agree that that is a bit misleading. Instead it should be the name of the request parameter to use, which should be (generally speaking) the same as the property in your model object.

```java
.file("ex.zip",  FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(mockFile));
```

With this a request parameter named `ex.zip` will be part of the request, however you have one that is named `file`.

```java
.file("file",  FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(mockFile));
```

Using the above line should fix it and properly bind to your object in turn properly invoking your validator.

On a side node, your validator should properly handle the `null` case as well or add a `@NotNull` on the field as well. The `@Valid` on the field doesn't do anything so you can remove that.